# Re-issuing AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm successfully using a RecursiveIteratorIterator to read all files and folders from my root uploads folder. To create an interface in which the user simply clicks on a file and it shows the contents or clicks on a file and is presented with appropriate information, I'm using AJAX requests. There are 3 main pages that display information in the following recursive manner:

showFiles.php: uploads/

showFileSubs.php: uploads/[clicked content]/

showSubs.php: uploads/[clicked content]/[sub clicked content]

showFiles.php: uploads/[clicked content]/[sub clicked content]/[sub sub clicked content]

and so forth until there is no more content or the user stops.

The problem I'm having is in getting showFiles.php to show content of uploads/[clicked content]/[sub clicked content]/[sub sub clicked content] since my $_GET ['toBase'] parameter does not seem to ever be set, despite information going into it. I'm confident (well somewhat) that information is going into it because on each click, the AJAX request creates an alert message box with the correct information.

I manually inserted the file path (all relative paths) into my RecursiveIteratorIterator and the information was correct, so I know it's not an issue with file paths. Each AJAX request is just a copy and paste from previous working ones, except for changing the file destination names, so it doesn't seem to be a careless typo.

I also have error_reporting turned on in all of my pages, however, there are none to be seen.

isDirectChild($path) gets the content from my RecurisveIteratorIterator and parses it into a relative path.

***showSubs.php***

```
<table border = "0" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0" id = "subParentTable"  >
                <tbody> 
                    <form>
                        <?php
                            $allCurrFiles = isDirectChild($searchIn);
                            for($currFile = 0; $currFile < count($allCurrFiles); $currFile++) {
                                    $img = getImgPath(trim(basename($allCurrFiles[$currFile])));
                                    echo("<tr>");
                                    echo("<td><button onClick = 'sendToBase(this)' type = 'button' name = 'butt' value = $allCurrFiles[$currFile] id = 'btn'><img src = $img /></button></td>");
                                #   echo("<td onClick = 'sendToBase(this)' ><img src = $img /></td>");
                                    echo("<td>$allCurrFiles[$currFile]</td>");
                                    echo("</tr>");
                            }
                        ?>
                    </form>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

***showFiles.php***

```
$toBase = null; // to avoid the error of undefined index in my if statement

    if(isset($_GET['toBase'])) {
        $toBase = $_GET['toBase'];
        echo("to base is $toBase <br />");
    } else {
        echo("to base is not set <br />");
    }


    if(($toBase == null) || (!isset($_GET['toBase']))) {
        // shows the immediate content of uploads/
    } else {
        // meant to show the content of uploads/[clicked content]/[sub clicked content]/[sub sub clicked content] 
    }
?>
<div id = "displayTable"></div>
<div id = "displayDir"></div>
</body>
```

EDIT: After realizing I forgot to create a div for my AJAX request to write to, it now writes, however, it's reloading the entire page on top of itself and the end result is quite ugly and unusable. This includes reloading a menu bar that is included in each page but I'm not sure why it's doing that. On the plus side, $toBase is now set...

EDIT 2: Added my AJAX request. I have only included the relative HTML as the rest is for external CSS files. Each page basically has the same HTML.

***AJAX Request in an external JS File in each page***

```
function sendToBase(x) { 
        var row = x.parentNode.innerText;
        var xmlhttp = "";
        alert("to base -- " + row); // alert does show the clicked file name, so I know row contains th
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "showFiles.php?toBase="+row, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
                document.getElementById("displayTable").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the JS code and the html.

Comment: @yossi I have included my AJAX and the HTML in the pages. Basically, it's loading my main menu (in an include since it is in another .php file) again and doing a bit of weird stuff with my CSS, such as altering where backgrounds are located. I can live with the CSS being a bit weird since it's not terribly bad and I can re-adjust other stuff but the main menu is being loaded again which I definitely don't want.

Comment: Seems like your JS is ok. 
it is hard to understand why your php is printing that extra data, without seeing or understanding how the complete pages looks like.
try to dumb the files to do nothing and show nothing, but checkpoints (an echo of a unique value in each `if`.

Comment: @yossi To be able to see everything on my page and start from barebones, I removed all CSS and added in a few echos at the troublesome page. I reloaded the page, ran through everything again and it worked! My tables loaded only once, everything only once in all 3 files, including the troublesome one. Either i'm misunderstanding AJAX but I thought it wouldn't load my CSS twice. Or am I wrong in thinking that? If it is meant to do that, how can I make it load only once?

Comment: PHP & CSS & HTML are just coe. they will be executed as you will set them. so twice is a code thing... now, try to put back the code parts one by one, and when you will get the error again - upload here that part of the code

Comment: @yossi I got it to work across different browsers! Basically, I put the CSS and main menu content in a separate .php file to see what would happen and it loaded only once! Since everything else is based on the actions that take place in showFiles.php, I simply used require("showFiles.php") and it's working. I think the reason was a pesky if statement that were in my main menu file and they would reload the page. Doesn't make a terrible lot of sense to me but I'll mull it over later.